# MVC search a LINQ query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, linq

I have a very simple query

```
var query = (from s in db.Stocks
             select s).ToList();
```

and now basically I want to then search that query to see if any of the stock objects names in the query contain "a"

I have this

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Name) )
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchModel.Name));
}
```

but I am getting this error

```
Cannot implicity convert type "system.collections.generic.ienumerable<etc etc> to system.collections.generic.list
```

How can I search my query result?

Its ok I have the answer
I just need to add .ToList to the end of my query statement like so

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Name) )
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchModel.Name)).ToList();
}
```

Comment: are you aware that loading a whole table into memory is not a good practice? The database is a lot better at doing searches than LINQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because in the first query

```
  var query = (from s in db.Stocks
             select s).ToList();
```

you have fixed the data type of the variable query to be List (`toList()`) . Now when you query it again with `Where` it returns IEnumerable and can't be assigned to the type List . You can do it in one line as in below

```
 var query = from s in db.Stocks
              where s.contains(searchModel.Name)
              select s
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchModel.Name)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can re-write the query as following:

```
var query = (from s in db.Stocks.ToList()
             where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchModel.Name) ? s.Contains(searchModel.Name) : true
             select s).ToList();
```

the new added line means: if SearchModel.Name is filled then search using it, otherwise do nothing

or you can keep your code as it, but add .ToList() after the table name, or remote .ToList() on the end of your query code which enforce the datatype of result